Fn key for disabling webcam and Indicator for muting mic not working
I've Ubuntu installed on my Asus laptop and the Fn key for disabling webcam (f10) is not working, when I press it nothing happens, the camera cancel graphic doesn't pop up, the orange indicator doesn't light up and the webcam doesn't get disabled. Other Fn keys for increasing brightness, volume are working fine.
The orange indicator for muting mic also doesn't work even though the mic gets disabled with the proper mic mute graphic on the screen when I press it's Fn key (f09). The indicator light for micmute turns on when I run echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/platform\:\:micmute/brightness and off when echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/platform\:\:micmute/brightness but it doesn't automatically happen with the pressing f09 key.
